# Has many through with different foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, has-many-through

I have the following `:has_many :through` relation.

**Associations**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :teams
  has_many :projects, :class_name => "Project", :through => :teams
  has_many :leads, :class_name => "Projects"

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :developers, :class_name => "Profile", :through => :teams
  belongs_to :lead, :class_name => "Profile", :foreign_key => "developer_lead"

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer, :class_name => "Profile"
  belongs_to :project
```

When I try to get a Profiles projects the relationship doesn't use the right key in the teams table.

**Rails C**

> 1.9.3p194 :001 > Profile.first.projects
>
> Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" LIMIT 1
>   Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "teams" ON "projects"."id" =
>   "teams"."project_id" WHERE **"teams"."profile_id" = 1**

It should be using `"teams"."developer_id" = 1`

I've tried using a `:foreign_key => "developer_id"` in both the Profile and Project models, but nothing seems to work.

I feel like the changes to the models I've been making aren't taking any effects, after each change I've been restarting the rails console though.

**Schema**

```
create_table "profiles", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
end

create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "developer_lead"
  t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false 
  t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
end

create_table "teams", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "developer_id"
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
end
```

Comment: `:foreign_key => "developer_id"` belongs with `has_many :teams`. What SQL does that generate?

Comment: Ah great, that worked. SQL: `SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "teams" ON "projects"."id" = "teams"."project_id" WHERE "teams"."developer_id" = 1`. If you throw that up in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:foreign_key => "developer_id"` belongs with `has_many :teams`.

Also, it makes your code clearer if you stick to rails conventions and end all foreign_key names with "_id", as in "developer_lead_id".